# How to match with an exact string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have small requirement.I want to search a string with exact match.
Suppose i want to search for None_1, i am searching for 'None_1' using /None_1/, but it is matching even "xxxNone" but my requirement is it should match only None_[any digit].
Here is my code

```
/^None_+[0-9]{?}/
```

So it should match only None_1 , None_2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should also anchor the expression at the end of the line. But that alone will not make it work. Your expression is wrong. I think it should be:

```
/^None_[0-9]+$/
```

- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits
- `None_` matches `None_`
- `$` matches the end of a line

If you only want to match *one* digit, remove the `+`.

---

Your original expression `/^None_+[0-9]{?}/` worked like this:

- `^` matches the beginning of a line
- `None` matches `None`
- `_+` matches one or more underscores
- `[0-9]` matches one digit
- `{?` matches an optional opening bracket `{`
- `}` matches `}`

Comment: I agree till your explanation of the curly brackets. If you want to match them you have to escape them. I have no idea what would happen, when used this way `[0-9]{?}` I think this is invalid. Normally it should look something like this `{1,5}` to say match 1 to 5 of `[0-9]`. Anyway +1

Comment: @stema: I also thought it is invalid. But I tried it and it matches them literally.

Comment: OK, tried it also and its really working (strange), learned something new, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`/^None_+[0-9]{?}$/`